# CDF of top $k$ value among $n$ RV's when the value of one of them is known

Tags: order-statistics

Suppose that $X_i$ is a random variable whose CDF if $F$ and pdf is $f$, $i=1,\cdots, n$. Assuming independency, the $m$-th highest value can be found using order statistics.

What would be the CDF of $X_1$ when $x_1$ is one of the top $k$ values among the realizations, $x_1,\cdots,x_n$, and one of the top $k$ values (except $x_1$) is kwown to be $x$?

Comment: This question is hard to parse.  Would the answer be a conditional distribution that depends on a parameter $x$?

Comment: @whuber, yes it should be. For example, my guess is that if $n=3$ and $k=2$, $X_1$ when it is among the top 2 values and the other one is $x$, the random variable is the highest among $X_1,X_2,X_3$ with probability $1-F(x)$ and it is the highest among $X_1$ and $X_3$ with probability $F(x)$? I want to confirm whether this reasoning is correct and want to know how to generalize this idea to general $(k,n)$.

Answer (score 1):

If $(X_1,\ldots,X_k)$ are the $k$ top observations out of $n$, their joint distribution is (up to a combinatoric constant)
$$F(\min\{x_i\})^{n-k} \prod_{i=1}^k f(x_i)$$
Hence the conditional distribution of $(X_1,\ldots,X_{k-1})$ given $X_k=x$ is (up to a combinatoric constant)
$$F(\min[\min_i\{x_i\},x])^{n-k} \prod_{i=1}^{k-1} f(x_i)\times f(x)$$ or
$$\mathbb{I}_{\min_i(x_i)<x} F(\min\{x_i\})^{n-k} \prod_{i=1}^{k-1} f(x_i)+\mathbb{I}_{\min_i(x_i)>x} F(x)^{n-k} \prod_{i=1}^{k-1} f(x_i)$$